# Having an issue with UITabBar

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, uitabbar

I already tried safe area checkbox in File Inspector . but it is not working well. and again it is showing me this issue .Have you any perfect solution.

[image]

[image]

This is the image with all constraints.

Comment: Show us some of your tries.? Via code or the constraints you have tried, it will help s to figure out the problem

Comment: Please provide us with some codes

Comment: strange !! looks like tabbar  height is not valid here. Please provide some more details is other device show perfect output

Comment: I am using TabBar constraints Trailing, Leading , Bottom, Top and Height For it.

Comment: top,bottom and height why 3

Comment: Set your bottom constrain with safe area you just enable same area. now you need to set constrain with it

Comment: just make sure your bottom constraint is with `safe area` not with superview

Comment: yes it is with safe area with bottom constraints

Comment: Remove top of your tabbar and check no issue of safe area here

Comment: @veerendrapratapsingh Could you please show all the constraints of your view controller (earlier i thought that it is tabbar controller but as now you clear that it is only tabbar)

Comment: I am adding an image with my constraints please see that.

Comment: Please show us screenshot of size inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting all the values of the constraints to 0, I had the same issue the images would come just above the label or the images were not proper, 
for constraints, if you are setting constraints for the top you need to set the same constraint for the bottom too...

I hope this could help you bit.

Comment: Try placing the tabBar again and this time don't add any constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* use a "loose" tab bar. You can only use a tab bar as supplied by a UITabBarController. Restructure your architecture to use a UITabBarController, and the tab bar will look correct on the iPhone X (and will be sized correctly in general, e.g. taller in portrait than in landscape on the iPhone).

Comment: "You can only use a tab bar as supplied by a UITabBarController" - Is this documented anywhere, or just something you've found from experience (offtopic, currently reading your Programming iOS 11 book and it's been very helpful)

Comment: @dcp Neither, it was just an attempt to solve OP’s problem. After all, we know that a tab bar in a tab bar controller _is_ sized correctly, so why doesn't the OP just use one?

Comment: "so why doesn't the OP just use one" Fair question, but in my case I already have many screens and "restructuring your architecture" is a major undertaking just to get a tab bar to look right.  The OP may be in that same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the height constraint of tabbar. Because the default height of tabbar is different in iPhone X compare to other iPhone devices.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Done . But not working proper. not its height increasing.

Comment: I can't get proper what are you saying. Can you please explain it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to update the height of tab bar

```
let ApplicationDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
DispatchQueue.main.async {
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone, ApplicationDelegate.window!.safeAreaInsets.top > 0 {
        let kTabBarHeight: CGFloat = 49.0/*default tab bar height*/ + ApplicationDelegate.window!.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        self.tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - kTabBarHeight, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: kTabBarHeight);
    }
}
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: What is (kPhoneXTabBarHeight) in this code can you explain me because it is showing me this error (Use of unresolved identifier 'kPhoneXTabBarHeight')

Comment: kPhoneXTabBarHeight is kTabBarHeight, it was written by mistake. I have updated it. Check now

Answer (score 0):

Do not add any constraints for images in UITabBar controller, and update the height of UITabbar and it's items for iPhoneX.

```
`override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    var newTabBarFrame = tabBar.frame
    var newTabBarHeight: CGFloat = 60

    if UIDevice.current.iPhoneX{
        newTabBarHeight = 102
    }
    newTabBarFrame.size.height = newTabBarHeight
    newTabBarFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - newTabBarHeight
    tabBar.frame = newTabBarFrame
    let numberOfItems = CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
    let customColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width / numberOfItems, height: tabBar.frame.height)
    tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: customColor, size: tabBarItemSize).resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero)
    // remove default border
    tabBar.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width + 4
    tabBar.frame.origin.x = -2
}`
```

Comment: I am not adding any constraints for image in UITabBar. So, Think this code is not for UITabBar

Comment: This code is for UITabbarController class, have you tried it?